# Submit pages to indexing by Google but censor the search terms in the page?

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap, meta-keywords

I am creating a site with phone numbers of staff, if someone googles the phone number I want them to find this site. However, on the site, before logging in, the number is partially censored (eg. 123-456-****).

These numbers are read from an SQL database by PHP. So http://example.com/staff.php?user=23 would give user 23. And I want Google to index this page under that phone number or other given search material, but I don't want to explicitly state the uncensored phone number in the actual site. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Simple... you can't, why would it be? I mean if Google and your users can't see it, why would they rank you for it?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, you can't rank in Google for a hidden term. That's called [cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en) and you can get a penalty for that. If Google gets to read the phone number, visitors must also be able to.

> Cloaking refers to the practice of presenting different content or URLs to human users and search engines. Cloaking is considered a violation of Google’s Webmaster Guidelines because it provides our users with different results than they expected.